# Having trouble understanding React syntax

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to understand React & Redux better. Lately I have been using the examples here: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/shopping-cart/src/reducers/products.js
I am having difficulty grasping these lines:
...action.products.reduce((obj, product) => {
 obj[product.id] = product
 return obj
 }, {})

and    [productId]: products(state[productId], action)

Can someone explain what's happening, please?

```
const byId = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_PRODUCTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.products.reduce((obj, product) => {
          obj[product.id] = product
          return obj
        }, {})
      }
    default:
      const { productId } = action
      if (productId) {
        return {
          ...state,
          [productId]: products(state[productId], action)
        }
      }
      return state
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rater unclear, but I'll try to answer to the best of my abilities. The `...` (three dots) is called the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and it's a way to "merge" an object (or array) into another object (or array). Here's an example:

```
const objA = {
    field_1: "my value",
    field_2: "my other value"
};
const newObject = {
    ...objA,
    field_3: "my third value"
};
console.log(newObject); // { 
                        //   field_1: "my value", 
                        //   field_2: "my other value", 
                        //   field_3: "my third value" 
                        // }
```

It is basically equivalent to the following:

```
const objA = {
    field_1: "my value",
    field_2: "my other value"
};
const newObject = Object.assign({}, objA, { field_3: "my third value" });
```

There's a lot more to it than my example, so please refer to the documentation.

The `[productId]: products(state[productId], action)` is a way to use a variable as an object key. That would be roughly equivalent to:

```
let objA = {
    field_1: "my value",
};
const myKey = "field_2";
objA[myKey] = "my other value";
```

Technically, it isn't React syntax, but rater ES6-7 syntax.